# x265 to x264 conversion buffers

Tags: ffmpeg

most x265 files won't play without buffering every 5 seconds so now I convert them with ffmpeg to x264 with "-crf 25" and "-vf format=yuv420p" but afterwards they still buffer;what's going on here?

OK so here is the output of ffprobe on the video clip:

```
ffprobe version n6.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.1.1 (GCC) 20230525
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-amf --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-lto --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libjxl --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-vulkan
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'video.1080p.BluRay.x265.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : VIDEO
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.5 + libmatroska v1.4.8
    creation_time   : 2018-10-20T02:21:06.000000Z
    Writing frontend: StaxRip v1.7.0.6
  Duration: 01:36:21.82, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5100 kb/s
  Chapters:
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 345.345000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 345.345000, end 717.341625
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 02
    Chapter #0:2: start 717.341625, end 920.920000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 03
    Chapter #0:3: start 920.920000, end 1126.291833
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 04
    Chapter #0:4: start 1126.291833, end 1442.065625
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 05
    Chapter #0:5: start 1442.065625, end 1856.855000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 06
    Chapter #0:6: start 1856.855000, end 2085.249833
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 07
    Chapter #0:7: start 2085.249833, end 2373.371000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 08
    Chapter #0:8: start 2373.371000, end 2902.900000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 09
    Chapter #0:9: start 2902.900000, end 3124.121000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 3124.121000, end 3200.822625
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 3200.822625, end 3582.078500
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 3582.078500, end 4108.687917
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 13
    Chapter #0:13: start 4108.687917, end 4355.517833
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 14
    Chapter #0:14: start 4355.517833, end 4676.046375
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 15
    Chapter #0:15: start 4676.046375, end 4885.881000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 16
    Chapter #0:16: start 4885.881000, end 5349.886208
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 17
    Chapter #0:17: start 5349.886208, end 5781.820000
      Metadata:
        title           : Chapter 18
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main 10), yuv420p10le(tv), 1800x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 5:3, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 4998377
      BPS-eng         : 4998377
      DURATION        : 01:36:21.818000000
      DURATION-eng    : 01:36:21.818000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 138625
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 138625
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 3612463661
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 3612463661
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-10-20 02:21:06
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-10-20 02:21:06
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 90004
      BPS-eng         : 90004
      DURATION        : 01:36:21.802000000
      DURATION-eng    : 01:36:21.802000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 271022
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 271022
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 65048307
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 65048307
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-10-20 02:21:06
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-10-20 02:21:06
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 1920x1080
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 17354
      BPS-eng         : 17354
      DURATION        : 01:34:38.953000000
      DURATION-eng    : 01:34:38.953000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 1766
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 1766
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 12319366
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 12319366
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v20.0.0 ('I Am The Sun') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2018-10-20 02:21:06
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2018-10-20 02:21:06
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
  Stream #0:3: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x360 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 90k tbr, 90k tbn (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      filename        : cover.jpg
      mimetype        : image/jpeg
```

And here is the command I used to encode to x264:

```
ffmpeg -i video.1080p.BluRay.x265.mkv -vf format=yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a copy -c:s copy video.1080p.BluRay.x264.mp4
```

I am using version 4.100.1 of Plex media server on my home network on cat6 cable. Plex is running from an Asustor NAS. I have a Samsung 4k TV (it doesn't support HDR) that runs version 5.64.1 of "Plex for Samsung" and platform version is 5.

Comment: You are probably mistaken about the problem—it’s not the codec that causes buffering. It’s the bitrate, the amount of data per time. Whatever you are using to play the video, it cannot get the data fast enough. Unfortunately, your question has no details whatsoever about the situation. If you add them, we can provide better help.